# How can I play a part of a song in Java?

Tags: java, audio

I want to play only a part of a song specifying the beginning and end of the sequence. I am new in using song in java. I wrote the following code, but something is wrong because is played the entire song. What should I modify?

```js
public class Song implements LineListener {
     
             
     /**
         * this flag indicates whether the playback completes or not.
         */
        boolean playCompleted;
         
        /**
         * Play a given audio file.
         * @param audioFilePath Path of the audio file.
         */
     
    
    void playFrame(String songName) {
        
      File audioFile = new File(songName);
         
      try {
             AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
  
             AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
  
             DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
  
             Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
  
             audioClip.addLineListener(this);
  
             audioClip.open(audioStream);
             
             int nrFrames = audioClip.getFrameLength();
             
             audioClip.setLoopPoints(nrFrames/3, nrFrames/3*2);
              
             audioClip.start();
              
             while (!playCompleted) {
                 // wait for the playback completes
                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
              
             audioClip.close();
              
         } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
             System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
             System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
}
    @Override
       public void update(LineEvent event) {
    LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();
     
    if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
        System.out.println("Playback started.");
        
    } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        playCompleted = true;
        System.out.println("Playback completed.");
    }

}
     
   
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        
        String fileName1 = "song1.wav";
  String fileName2 = "song2.wav";
        Song player = new Song();
        player.playFrame(fileName1);
        
        Song player2 = new Song();
        player2.playFrame(fileName2);
    }
 
}
```

Comment: According to the Javadoc, it seems `setLoopPoints` will work when you play a loop with the `loop` method, not with the `start` method. I can't answer your question though...

Comment: @Diana, Since you are using RIFF wave, read the samples your self and pump them to your audio backend. The you know exactly what happens in your DSP pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Your initiate the loop points but then don't start the 'loop':

```
 int nrFrames = audioClip.getFrameLength()   
 audioClip.setLoopPoints(nrFrames/3, nrFrames/3*2);
```

and from checking the Clip doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setLoopPoints(int,%20int)

It seems like you need to use the `.loop(int count)` method, instead of the `.start()` method. You would just set the count to 1 in this case to play it once.

Edit: Just saw this was made as a comment by someone else while I was typing it up, sorry!